# Python Iterate Through List of Lists of Objects and Call a Method

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a list of lists of objects in using for loops. At the end of each iteration when I have isolated one object I am trying to call a method from that object. The problem is that each time I iterate through I am getting the a copy of the 2nd list acting in place of the 1st and 2nd list. I don't get it at all. Here is my code.

```
from sys import stdout

class Map:

    def show(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            print '' #\n
            for room in row:
                stdout.write(' ')#space
                room.show()

    def __init__(self, rooms):
        x_list, y_list = [],[]
        for room in rooms:
            x_list.append(room.loc[0])
            y_list.append(room.loc[1])
        great_x = max(x_list)
        great_y = max(y_list)
        self.grid = [[None] * (great_x+1)] * (great_y+1)
        for room in rooms:
            self.grid[room.loc[1]][room.loc[0]] = room
```

Room is a class that has attributes loc which is the x y location of the room in the form [x,y]. Room also has a method called show() which just prints out the string for that room.

The outcome of the above is:
[Red] [Bro]
[Red] [Bro]

it's supposed to be:
[Bla] [Blu]
[Red] [Bro]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is creating many references to the *same* list

```
self.grid = [[None] * (great_x+1)] * (great_y+1)
```

You need to use a list comprehension like this

```
self.grid = [[None] * (great_x+1) for y in (great_y+1)]
```

This creates a new `[None] * (great_x+1)` for each `y`

Comment: THanks alot! Never thought about that.